# Rails project directory not visible in Finder OS X 10.9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, osx-mavericks

I created some basic Rails applications in the past using OS X 10.6 and 10.8 under Ruby 1.9.3 & Rails 3, and never had this problem.

When I run:

```
rails new projectName
```

It creates a new project in that specified directory, but when I go to look at it in the Finder, the folder is not there. However, if I type `ls` in the terminal it lists that project directory as being in whatever directory I created it in.

Is this a bug with OS X 10.9 or Rails 4? I've tried searching for this issue with no results so I'm hoping I'm not the only one having this issue.

Comment: OS X 10.9, Rails 4.0.1 here and it works as expected. What does `ls -l` say? Any weird permissions or owned by incorrect user?

Comment: Also can you open the project folder using Cmd+Shift+G in Finder?

Comment: ls -l lists all the files/folders inside the folder I cd to including the new rails project. It makes me wonder if some kind of strange caching issue is going on with Finder

Comment: Cmd+Shift+G lets me view the Rails project folder contents and strangely after I do that, the folder is visible in Finder

Comment: I suspect you have some corruption in your directory information if you can't see it in the Finder. When's the last time you let Disk Utility repair permissions and settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cd <rails proj dir>
$ ls -l  # verify that you can see your projects
$ open . # Will open that directory in Finder.
```

Comment: This works but still strange I need to do this when in the past the directory would automatically appear in Finder

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same issue. Delete the directory you just created. Run the rails new command, but remove -d mysql. For some reason, when you create a rails app with mysql, it does not add the @ at the end of your permissions. Not sure why, but this is the best workaround I was able to find.